# Ruby/Rails - Check If Child Id Exists Within Record of HABTM Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a set of resources called Tasks and Posts and there are in a has_and_belongs_to_many (HABTM) relationship with each other.

There is also a join table connecting their values.

```
create_table 'posts_tasks', :id => false do |t|
   t.column :post_id, :integer
   t.column :task_id, :integer
end
```

So my question is how do I check to see if the id of a specific task exists within the array created from @post.tasks?

```
irb(main):011:0> @post = Post.find(1)
=> #<Post id: 2, comment: "blah blah", created_at: "2011-10-18 03:40:30", updated_at:
irb(main):012:0> @post.tasks
=> [#<Task id: 1, description: "Test 1", created_at: "2011-10-18 03:
   22:05", updated_at: "2011-10-18 03:22:05">, #<Task id: 3, description: "Test 3",
   created_at: "2011-10-18 03:22:21", updated_at: "2011-10-18 03:22:21
    ">]
```

So my question is whats the ruby way for writing does "@task = Task.find(2)" exist within @post.tasks and if so return true or false?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@post.tasks.map(&:id).include?(task_id)
```

Where `task_id` is the id of the task you want to check. To explain this a little bit, you're taking the list of tasks, mapping them to an array of their ids, and then checking to see if the id in question is in that array. If you're not familiar with `map` you should check it out, it's awesome.

[ruby-docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-map)

Comment: Just want to point out that this is not necessarily the best answer. The right way to do this will depend on what data you have already loaded, and what future questions you intend to ask of it. Database queries are expensive! Minimize them.

Answer (score 13):

```
@post.tasks.where(:id => task_id).present?
```

Is much lighter compared to what Gabelsman has suggested.

Comment: This makes `n` queries if you are checking `n` tasks. But still better than the accepted answer.

Comment: It doesn't have to. You can pass an array of `task_ids`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you named your `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `:posts` then doing something like this in Rails is very optimized:

`@post.task_ids.include?(task.id)`

I noticed that the two answer provided here result in `n` select statements. But doing it with `task_ids` caches the first query and the rest does not require a `SELECT` statement from the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) method for that:

```
@post.tasks.exists?(id: task_id)
```